# Determining Points of $\mathbb{C}$ where $f(z)$ is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Sorry for the question but i'm partially confused about the result and i'm hoping someone can help. here we go

> Stating clearly any result you use, determine the set of points in $\mathbb{C}$ where the following functions are differentiable.
>   $$f(z) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}  \frac{z^4}{|z|^2} ~ \text{if z}\neq 0\\ 0 ~\text{if z} = 0\end{matrix}\right. $$

so here's where i'm at so far.
let $z\neq 0$, then we use euler's form giving
$$f(z) = \frac{|z|^4(\cos{4\theta}+i\sin{4\theta})}{|z|^2}$$ via De'moivres $\implies$ (subbing |z| = r)
$$f(z) = r^2(\cos{4\theta}+i\sin{4\theta})$$

From here, we consider f as $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where $f(u(r,\theta),v(r,\theta)) = u(r,\theta)+i v(r,\theta)$

for f to be holomorphic (this is one of the problems i've got already...the phrasing of the question says to determine the points in $\mathbb{C}$ where f is differentiable, and not necessarily holomorphic?)

either way...crack on: for f to be holomorphic, u,v must be Real-differentiable (which they are) and the CR-Equations must be satisfied.

Using $$u(r,\theta)=r^2 \cos{4\theta}~\&~v(r,\theta) = r^2\sin{4\theta}$$

we need to satisfy
$$u_{r}= \frac{1}{r}v_{\theta}, ~\&~ v_r = -\frac{1}{r}u_{\theta}$$

Running the calculations we have
$$u_r = 2r \cos{4\theta}$$
$$u_{\theta} = -4r^2 \sin{4\theta}$$
$$v_{r} = 2r \sin{4\theta}$$
$$v_{\theta} = 4r^2 \cos{4\theta}$$

substituing into the above values gives
$$u_{r}= \frac{1}{r}v_{\theta} \implies 2r \cos{4\theta} = 4r \cos{4\theta} \implies 1 = 2$$
and
$$v_{r}= -\frac{1}{r}u_{\theta} \implies 2r \sin{4\theta} = 4r \sin{4\theta} \implies 1 = 2$$

what have i done wrong? if it's nothing...does this mean that the function isn't differentiable at any point $(z \neq 0 )\in \mathbb{C}$?

cheers for reading.

> i think it may be a bit of a long day on my behalf, and i think i'm just doing something stupid at this point...but tbh i just can't see it right now

If i minus one side from the other and then compare the two i get
$$(r,\theta) = (1/2,\theta)$$ satisfies both equations, otherwise nothing else does as Cos and sin are never zero at the same time.

does this mean that f(z) is holomorphic on the disk of radius 1/2?

Cheers for reading.

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: I have no idea what your final paragraph is about with $(r,\theta)=(1/2,\theta)$, nor where you're getting being holomorphic on the disk of radius $1/2$. Note that since $1\ne 2$, you must have $r=0$ *or* $\cos 4\theta = \sin 4\theta = 0$. Now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is *real* differentiable, indeed smooth, for $z\ne 0$, being the quotient of two smooth functions. Now, note that for $z\ne 0$ we can rewrite
$$f(z) = \frac{z^4}{|z|^2} = \frac{z^4}{z\bar z} = \frac{z^3}{\bar z};$$
thus, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z} \ne 0$, and so $f$ is not holomorphic.

Now, what about at $z=0$? Write down the difference quotient
$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{h^3}{\bar h}}h = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^2}{\bar h}.$$
Note that
$$\left|\frac{h^2}{\bar h}\right| = \left| h\cdot \frac{h}{\bar h}\right| =  |h|\left|\frac h{\bar h}\right| = |h| \to 0,$$
and so $f'(0)=0$ and $f$ *is* complex differentiable at $0$.

Comment: thanks for that, it's just been a very long couple of days and i think my minds gone to mush. Just a quick question, $z \neq 0$ is real differentiable because the functions are differentiable in the real plane, but because the CR arent satisfied then theyre not holomorphic right?

Comment: Right. if $f$ were holomorphic, the product rule would tell you that $|z|^2$ would be, but there it's easy to see that C.R. fails away from the origin.